# TypeScript dynamic object properties

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

In TypeScript, it is possible for a type declaration to allow for dynamic object properties?

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
    [everything else]: any;
}

let animal = <Animal>{ name: "Kitty", type: "cat" };

animal.name; // Would be treated as string

animal.type; // Would allow compilation and be treated as any
```

I would like these extra properties to be allowed dynamically, without having to add them to the type declaration. Using TypeScript 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
    type?: any;
}
```

But I would suggest using an Enum for type like this:

```
enum AnimalType {Cat, Dog, ...};

class Animal {
    name: string;
    type?: AnimalType;
}
```

Comment: What about `colour` for example? I want the extra properties to be allowed without having to add them to the type.

Comment: This should not give an error at all: See http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20animal%20%3D%20%3CAnimal%3E%7B%20name%3A%20%22Kitty%22%2C%20type%3A%20%22cat%22%20%7D%3B

Comment: It does. http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20animal%20%3D%20%3CAnimal%3E%7B%20name%3A%20%22Kitty%22%2C%20type%3A%20%22cat%22%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aanimal.type%20%3D%20123%3B

Comment: I think you have to use it similar to a map but I am not sure if that is a good idea: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20animal%20%3D%20%3CAnimal%3E%7B%20name%3A%20%22Kitty%22%2C%20type%3A%20%22cat%22%20%7D%3B%0Aanimal%5B'type'%5D%20%3D%20123%3B