# How to access object properties of a custom interface using a string in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I need to access the properties of my object dynamically using a given string as the key.

I have checked the following, but I can't find the answer I am looking for:

[TypeScript dynamic object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888551/typescript-dynamic-object-properties)

[Typescript dynamic access property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417520/typescript-dynamic-access-property)

The error happens here:

```
state.value[container][id] // TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'
```

When calling method 'getEntity' should I be passing an ENUM for the property instead of a string?

Below is a simplified example of my code - errors are on lines 57 and 69:

```js
// interfaces for entity types - including these in this example seems unnecessary
import {
  TaskFinances,
  Plan,
  Boundary,
  BoundaryMapList
} from 'DTOs'

// for pulling data from REST
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

// VueJS composition AIP components
import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

// I want to imply that the State interface below is made up of string:unknown pairs
// so that I can reference it using a string key in the <getEntity> method below

interface Stately {
  [key: string]: unknown
}
interface State extends Stately {
  plans: { [key: number]: Plan };
  taskFinances: { [key: number]: TaskFinances };
  boundaryPointsByField: Boundary[];
}

const props: State = {
  plans: {},
  taskFinances: {},
  boundaryPointsByField: []
}

const state = ref(props)
// I reference the properties of state using state.value.xxx because it is using the Vue3 Composition API Ref syntax

// Reduced to 2 lines following D.R.Y. principles
function getTaskFinances(activityId: number): Promise<TaskFinances> {
  const taskFinances = getEntity(activityId, 'taskFinance', 'taskFinances') as unknown as Promise<TaskFinances>
  return taskFinances
}

// Reduced to 2 lines following D.R.Y. principles
function getBoundaryPointsByField(fieldId: number): Promise<BoundaryMapList> {
  const boundaryPoints = getEntity(fieldId, 'boundaryPointsByField', 'boundaryPointsByField') as unknown as Promise<BoundaryMapList>
  return boundaryPoints
}

// Reduced to 2 lines following D.R.Y. principles
function getPlan(planId: number): Promise<Plan> {
  const plan = getEntity(planId, 'plan', 'plans') as unknown as Promise<Plan>
  return plan
}

// generic method to return requested entities and add them to my state object
async function getEntity(id: number, api: string, container: string): Promise<unknown> {
  try {
    const entity: unknown = state.value[container][id] // THROWS typescript error -TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'-
    if (entity) {
      return entity
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(container, id, err)
  }

  const url = `${api}${id}`
  try {
    const { data }: AxiosResponse<unknown> = await axios.get(url)
    console.log(api + ':', data)
    state.value[container][id] = data  // THROWS typescript error -TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'-
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

// interface for my exported uiState object - I use this interface elsewhere in the app so I am exporting it
export interface IUIState {
  getBoundaryPointsByField: (fieldId: number) => Promise<BoundaryMapList>;
  getTaskFinances: (activityId: number) => Promise<TaskFinances>;
  getPlan: (planId: number) => Promise<Plan>;
}

// export my uiState object
export const uiState: IUIState = {
  getBoundaryPointsByField,
  getTaskFinances,
  getPlan
}
```

Comment: Can you use better types? E.g. `container: string` should probably be `keyof` something.

Comment: keyof is new to me, as I am pretty new to TypeScript (I guess that shows!) - I am looking into how to implement that in this context now, but if you have any suggestions I would appreciate them ;) Thanks for your time @johnsharpe

Comment: not getting it ;(
```
async function getEntity<K extends keyof State>(id: number, api: string, container: K): Promise<unknown> {
```

Comment: thanks @rie, but that makes my props object totally generic. It makes more sense to me to pass in container as a keyof State as apposed to a generic string (as johnsharpe suggested) but I do not know how to do that correctly.

Comment: @user2115620 Looking at the params of this function `getEntity` and given this `state.value[container][id]`, are you sure you would have *dynamic* "entity factory" named with numbers? Because that would actually evaluate to something like: `state.value.getAnotherMethod['123']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is intended.

Where you access your state here

```
 const entity: unknown = state.value[container][id]
```

`state.value[container]` is now of type `unknown`. You cannot try and access `[id]` behind it because TS has no clue if that even exists on `state.value[container]`. It's unknown. That is the downfall of using unknown. If you know your API responses, create interfaces for them and declare those as possible types for your state.
Otherwise, if you want to force it to work without types, you'd have to use `any` instead of unknown.

You can see this behaviour reproduced [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpANgT2QbwChlkBtAawhwC5kBnMKUAcwF1aBXEckAewHcQhAL6FCWCGHoZItdJgi5kAXgKiJUgEYrpC0gCIEvcHFDR9rQpoPAAJhYDcQA). You can see how the variable `b` is of type unknown and throws an error already. If you change the type to `any` in the interface, it will work but you won't get any type-safety.